# Is it possible to have different colormaps in a highchart heatmap? Or to gray out some of the items?

Tags: r, highcharts, plotly, heatmap, r-highcharter

I want to create a heatmap with two different kind of values. For the sake of some example, let's imagine, I have a number of animals "a1", "a2" and "a3" and a set of body-part-lenghts, let's say a scientist measured the length of the "left arm", "right arm", "left leg" and "right leg".

Now lets imagine that the arm measurements of "a2" and "a3" were taken by an intern and we want to make clear that this measurement is distinct (e.g. not as reliable) from the others.

One way I could think of is graying out these two measurements a bit? The color should still be the same, just not as strong. Also great would be to simply use another color scale.

As a bonus question, let's say the left leg of a1 was forgotten, is there a good way to make this element completely gray then?

I use R as my programming language.
I preferably use highcharter as the library, but also plotly would be OK for me to use.

Here is some code that should make it possible to play around a bit:

```
library(highcharter)

mat <- matrix(data=rnorm(4*3, 1,.2), nrow = 4)
rownames(mat) <- c("left arm", "right arm", "left leg", "right leg")
colnames(mat) <- c("a1", "a2", "a3")

hchart(mat, type="heatmap")

mat["left leg", "a1"] <- NA

unreliable_info_mat <- matrix(FALSE, nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
rownames(unreliable_info_mat) <- c("left arm", "right arm", "left leg", "right leg")
colnames(unreliable_info_mat) <- c("a1", "a2", "a3")
unreliable_info_mat[c("left arm", "right arm"), c("a2", "a3")] <- TRUE
unreliable_info_mat
```

[image: this is not yet grayed out but already a heatmap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option to have more than one colorAxis in the chart. Basically, you denote which observations are "unreliable" and split up the dataframe into two. Add each individual series to the plot and then we can set up two different colorAxis in `hc_colorAxis`.

You'll notice the second series has `colorAxis = 1`. This technically means the second colorAxis since the default is `colorAxis = 0`.

Let me know if you have any questions. Hopefully this is inline with what you're trying to achieve.

```
library(highcharter)

# assumes stringsAsFactors = T
set.seed(101)
mat <- data.frame(values=round(rnorm(4*3, 1,.2),2),
                  limbs = rep(c("left arm", "right arm", "left leg", "right leg"), 3),
                  animals = rep(c("a1", "a2", "a3"), 4),
                  reliable = as.factor(sample(c(T,F), 12, replace = T)))

mat[1,1] = NA

split_df = split(mat, mat$reliable)
names(split_df) = c("unreliable", "reliable")

highchart(type = "chart") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category", categories = levels(mat$animals), reversed = TRUE) %>%
  hc_yAxis(categories = levels(mat$limbs)) %>%
  hc_add_series(split_df$unreliable, hcaes(x = animals, y = limbs, value = values), type = 'heatmap', 
                showInLegend = T, name = "Unreliable", dataLabels = list(enabled = T)) %>%
  hc_add_series(split_df$reliable, hcaes(x = animals, y = limbs, value = values), type = 'heatmap', 
                colorAxis = 1, showInLegend = T, name = "Reliable",dataLabels = list(enabled = T), nullColor = "grey") %>%
  hc_colorAxis(
    list(minColor = "grey", maxColor = "grey"),
    list(minColor ="powderblue", maxColor = "cornflowerblue")
  ) %>%
  hc_tooltip(formatter = JS("function() { return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br>' + this.point.xf + ' ~ ' + 
                             this.point.yf + '<br> Value: ' + this.point.value }")) %>%
  hc_colors(c("grey","cornflowerblue")) # to update legend icon colors
```

[image: animation]

Comment: This seems to be a very good approach, however I have two questions:
Where can I decide the order of the xAxis? If I type `hc_xAxis(type = "category", categories = rev(unique(mat$animals)))` then the plotted data is incorrect. Is there an elegant way to decide about the order? And how can I ever be sure that the correct labels are on my axis if it is so easy to make a mistake? What is a good approach? My second question is, what can I do about NA? So instead of having an empty field having a gray field but without axis.

Comment: It's a blessing and a curse. Highcharter is very customizable but it comes with a 'complexity' cost where it may take some time to understand all of its capabilities. To answer your questions, you can use `hc_xAxis(..., reversed = TRUE)` switching the order. To color NAs you can do `hc_add_series(..., nullColor = "grey")`. I'd also recommend checking out the `highcharter` documentation and the highcharts API! I've modified my code above to include your ?'s for posterity.

Comment: In your new code you forgot to make mat$animals and mat$limbs factors, so it does not work. Once you do that it seems to work. However it is still unclear to me, how exactly highcharts figures out what tile to put where and how to label the axis. I wrote a seperate question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76947450/how-do-i-decide-about-the-order-of-categoric-values-in-heatmap-with-highcharter

Comment: Ah my mistake. I'm using an earlier version of R so by default, strings become factors when creating a new `data.frame`.