# How do I decide about the order of categoric values in heatmap with highcharter?

Tags: r, highcharts, heatmap, r-highcharter

Let's say you have given a long dataframe with all data you need for a heatmap. Is there an elegant way to decide in which order the categories appear on the axis?

Let me give you an example:

```
library(highcharter)
long_data <- data.frame("xaxis"=c("startX","startX","secondX","secondX","lastX","lastX"),
                        "yaxis"=c("Y2","Y1","Y2","Y1","Y1","Y2"),
                        "value"=c(12,11,22,21,31,32))

highchart(type = "chart") %>% 
  hc_add_series(long_data, hcaes(x = xaxis, y = yaxis, value = value), type = 'heatmap', 
                showInLegend = T, name = "showcase", dataLabels = list(enabled = T)) %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(list(minColor = "blue", maxColor = "red"))
```

gives

[image: Heatmap without labels]

Two questions:

How am I supposed to know what 0, 1 and 2 mean? For me as a programmer I seem to have no way of finding that out without looking at the original data.

I want to be able to decide about the order of x-Axis and y-Axis, let's say startX, secondX, lastX (left to right) and Y1, Y2 (top to bottom). How should I do that? Ideally, I do not want to rely on the order in `long_data` for that but instead have a parameter in highcharts that does this for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want axis labels instead of numbers you could switch to `hchart()` which under the hood calls `hc_xAxis` and `hc_yAxis` and adds the labels from your data. Or you can do that manually using e.g. `hc_xAxis(categories = sort(unique(long_data$xaxis)))`.

Concerning the order of the categories on the axes, as pointed out by @Jamie in the comments we could reverse the order of the categories using e.g. `hc_yAxis(reversed = TRUE)` in case of the y axis and there is also a `dataSorting` option to reorder the categories based on another column.

Besides that one option would be to set the order by converting to factors with the order of the levels set according to your desired order, e.g. in the code below I reverse the order for `yaxis`:

```r
library(highcharter)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo

long_data <- data.frame(
  "xaxis" = c("startX", "startX", "secondX", "secondX", "lastX", "lastX"),
  "yaxis" = c("Y2", "Y1", "Y2", "Y1", "Y1", "Y2"),
  "value" = c(12, 11, 22, 21, 31, 32)
)

long_data$yaxis <- factor(long_data$yaxis, levels = c("Y2", "Y1"))

hchart(long_data, hcaes(x = xaxis, y = yaxis, value = value),
  type = "heatmap",
  showInLegend = TRUE, name = "showcase",
  dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)
) %>%
  hc_colorAxis(minColor = "blue", maxColor = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: You can reverse the order of the Axes by setting `reversed = TRUE`. You can also use `hc_add_series(..., dataSorting = list(...))`. To sort by a specific column (key) in the data.